# Proving an element exists between the supremum and infimum of two sets

Tags: real-analysis

My question reads:

If for sets A,B, $\sup A<\inf B$, then $\exists$ $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<c<b$, $\forall\ a\in\ A,\ b\in\ B.$

This is what I have written as a proof, is this correct?

My proof:

Since $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $A$, $\forall\ a\in\ A$, we have $a\leq\ \sup A$ and since $\inf B$ is a lower bound for $B$ it follows that for all $\forall\ b\in\ B$, $b\geq\ \inf B$. Consider $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that we have  $\sup A<c=\frac{\sup A+\inf B}{2}<\inf B$ and since $a\leq\ \sup A$,  $b\geq\ \inf B$, then $a<c<b$.

Comment: This is correct, except for some awkward edge cases.  Since we require $c$ to be a real number, we can't use the formula $c = (\sup A + \inf B)/2$ if either of the two values in the denominator are infinite.  But for the most part this doesn't happen, since $\inf B = -\infty$ would make it impossible for $\sup A$ to be $< \inf B$, and $\inf B = +\infty$ only happens if $B$ is empty.  It's still true that there is a real number between $\sup A$ and $\inf B$, just not necessarily one that can be obtained by taking the midpoint.

Comment: It's correct although I would have finished with  $\forall a\in A\;\forall b\in B\;(a\leq \sup A<c<\inf B\leq b).$

Comment: @ErickWong. Good point, as  the Q does not exclude the cases where A or B is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct! Where you say "This is equal to", it would be better to say "This implies". And you can make the presentation of this proof shorter, like so:

Suppose $\sup A<\inf B$, and let $c=\frac{\sup A+\inf B}{2}$. Then for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, we have $a\leq\sup A<c<\inf B\leq b$.